# Building GUI For Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

First of all, here is the simple application I build using C# in Visual Studio 2010, the filename is *program.cs*, all process will be displayed in command prompt.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (input)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("A");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("B");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("C");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("default");
            break;
    }
}
```

I want to build a GUI to make it more user friendly.

I created a form with a *ComboBox*, a *Label*, and a *Button*. The values in the ComboBox are [1,2,3,default]. I want to let the user select a value in the ComboBox, hit the Button, and the program will update the label to [A,B,C,default].

How can I keep the logic in program.cs, and achieve the above goal?

I created a form and visual studio generate a Form1.cs that looks like this

```
namespace quickTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

So I think the problem I ran into is I don't know how *program.cs* can get/set value of Form1

In `Main()`, I added `Application.Run(new Form1());` so it runs the form instead of command prompt, but then I'm stuck. I tried `comboBox1.SelectedValue` but I can only get value in From1.cs and not program.cs, I need it to be in program.cs so I can apply the logic.

Just for clarification, this is just a sample I build. The actual *program.cs* contains a lot more logic but I don't think it's affect what I want to do here so I didn't put it in the description. I need a way to get and set value from *program.cs* to the form.

Comment: It would be easier to create a new project of type "Winform" and start to enter your logic there, rather than convert a console project to a winform project.  Calling Application.Run(new Form1()) is not a great idea.

Comment: Create a new Windows Forms project, then create a class that does what your 'program.cs' does now

Comment: and why did this get downvoted?  It's a well constructed question

Comment: @paqogomez The problem is that this is a business application, there are many other cs files and functions (maybe like 30 other cs files), which makes it really hard to rewrite the program into a winform project. I didn't build the application, I was only told to modify and build a GUI for it.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 is right, but if you really must redirect your console output, you could try something [like this](http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/)  This means that you are parsing strings for all your data.  A total pain in the a$$ way to go IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the best solution is adding a GUI to a console application, but I've been in a similar situation before and was able to do it successfully. The best option would be to refactor the logic into libraries that could be referenced from a separate GUI application.

Create events in the form class and subscribe to them from program.cs to drive the logic that needs to happen. You can pass values to and from the logic with your EventArgs class. That is essentially what you do when you write the code that drives a form, you're just offloading it to a separate class.

**Update: Added Example Code**

This is basic event-based programming. Through the use of generics we can greatly reduce the amount of boilerplate code, but it would be good to get an understanding of the delegates we're creating automatically through generics. Shortcuts can be a hindrance if you don't understand how they work (or don't) when bugs arise.

Events how to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx

Generic delegates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx

For an example I created a pair of forms. `MainWindow` has a textbox `OutputBox`, and `DetachedForm` has a combobox `OptionComboBox` and a button `TriggerButton`, which we will use to fire the event.

MainWindow Class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DetachedForm detachedForm = new DetachedForm();
        detachedForm.SelectionMade += new EventHandler<SelectionMadeEventArgs>(detachedForm_SelectionMade);            
        detachedForm.Show();
    }

    void detachedForm_SelectionMade(object sender, SelectionMadeEventArgs e)
    {
        OutputBox.Text = e.ActualSelection;
    }
}
```

DetachedForm Class

```
public partial class DetachedForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<SelectionMadeEventArgs> SelectionMade;

    public DetachedForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnSelectionMade(SelectionMadeEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<SelectionMadeEventArgs> handler = SelectionMade;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void TriggerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OptionComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            SelectionMadeEventArgs args = new SelectionMadeEventArgs(OptionComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
            OnSelectionMade(args);
        }
    }
}

public class SelectionMadeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SelectionMadeEventArgs(String actualSelection)
    {
        ActualSelection = actualSelection;
    }

    public String ActualSelection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on how I can approach this? I created an event 'private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}' in From1.cs, but how can I references the value in program.cs? I made program inherit from Form1 so it can access the functions, but I don't know what's next.

Comment: Updated with code examples. To send data to the form, expose methods or properties on the form which can be called from program.cs. While it is possible to expose public properties from the form, it keeps things tidy if you can pass what's needed in the custom EventArgs class.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a public function or property in Form1.cs that gets/sets the value of the combo box, then in program.cs you can access that function to set or get the combo box.